# Driving force of a mass-spring system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, oscillators

In a horizontal mass-spring system with one spring, an external source supplies a driving force from one end. I know that the force is periodic but I have trouble understanding the direction of the force. If it is periodic, does it mean that its direction changes with the displacement of the mass, or does it only act in one direction?

Answer (score 0):

You could have either case (a force acting in one direction or switching from one direction to another) depending on how the force is specified.

A simple sinusoid such as $\boldsymbol{F}=(F_0\sin\omega t)\boldsymbol{\hat x}$ (where $\boldsymbol{\hat x}$ is the unit vector in the x-direction) changes directions during each cycle when $\omega t$ is between $\pi+2n\pi$ and $2\pi+2n\pi$, where $n$ is an integer.

In contrast, $\boldsymbol
 F=(F_0+F_0\sin\omega t)\boldsymbol{\hat x}$ points only in the positive x-direction, for example, when it isn't zero at $\pi+2n\pi$.

I made a [page with a bunch of little animations](http://john.maloney.org/Programming/pythonboing.htm) of driven motion; the applied-force case is example #8.

For a spring–mass system, the periodic force is doing work on the system when the mass is moving in the same direction the force is pointing. If the directions are opposite, then the system is doing work on the mass. These additions and subtractions of energy generally balance out. However, if the force changes directions at a certain speed such that it always does work on the system—corresponding to the resonance frequency—the system response will “blow up” with an infinite amplitude.

In contrast, spring–mass–**damper** systems avoid the catastrophe of an arbitrarily high response because some kinetic energy is converted into thermal energy in the damper, and this conversion scales up with increasing speed.

Comment: You can have forced (driven) periodic motion under the efect of a force that changes direction periodically.

Answer (score 0):

"Periodic" is not enough to define the force completely. The force has to be given explicitly, by an equation. Then you know if it does or not change direction. Usualy, when the example of driven SHO is treated in textbooks, the force for the 1D case may be given as $F= F_0 cos(\omega t)$.This type of force is not just periodic but a harmonic periodic force. It has one direction for half a period and opposite direction for the other half. The motion follows the force with some phase difference which depends on the diference between the frequency of the force and the frequency of the free oscillations of the system.